# Finding critical points of $dX/dt = k(\alpha - x)(\beta -x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I need to find the critical points and the assess the stability of the following equation and describe its behavior as t approaches infinity if X(0) = 0.

$\frac{dX}{dt} = k(\alpha - x)(\beta -x)$

I was able to separate the variables and solve the differential equation with the initial condition. I got

$\frac{ (\alpha - x)}{(\beta -x)} = \frac {\alpha}{\beta} e^{k(\beta - \alpha)t} $

I am now having trouble getting the critical points from this and sketching a phase diagram. Can someone please help?

Comment: Ok so you solved the ODE. From calculus, you may recall that to find critical points, you take the derivative and set it equal to $0$, i.e. $\frac{dX}{dt} = 0$, which gives you your original equation but equal to $0$. Thus, no need to solve the ODE

Comment: I see! I guess I was overthinking. There is another part to this question however, which is to describe the behavior of X as t approaches infinity when $ \alpha = \beta > 0$ in two different scenarios: 1) when x(0) < $\alpha$ and 2) when x(0) > $\alpha$. Could you help me with this?

Comment: We are told to assume that k > 0.

Answer (score 1):

**Part 1:** Looks like you understand setting $x' = 0$ and how to find the two critical points:

$$x = \alpha, \beta$$

**Part 2:** Plot the direction field for $k \gt 0 = 1$, with $\alpha = \beta > 0 = 1$ (try those with other values and convince yourself that it doesn't really change things qualitatively, it just moves the single critical point):

$~~~~~~~~~~~~$[image]

Do you notice the single critical point that is equal to one in the direction field? What happens if you choose an initial point above the critical point? What happens if you choose an initial point below the critical point?

**Case 1:** Using the values of Part 2, choose an $x(0) \lt \alpha = -1$ (since $\alpha = 1$) and describe the behavior of $x(t)$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$. We have:

$$x' = (1 - x)(1 -x), x(0) = -1$$

Solving this (it is separable), we have

$$x(t) = \dfrac{2 t-1}{2 t+1}$$

A plot of $x(t)$ shows:

$~~~~~~~~~~~~$[image]

Do you see what happens as $t \rightarrow \infty$? What is the limit?

If we plot the direction field using the initial condition, we have:

[image]

**Case 2:** Using the values of Part 2, choose an $x(0) \gt \alpha = 2$ (since $\alpha = 1$) and describe the behavior of $x(t)$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$. We have:

$$x' = (1 - x)(1 -x), x(0) = 2$$

Solving this (it is separable), we have

$$x(t) = \dfrac{t-2}{t-1}$$

A plot of $x(t)$ shows:

$~~~~~~~~~~~~$[image]

Do you see what happens as $t \rightarrow \infty$? What is the limit?

If we plot the direction field using the initial condition, we have:

[image]

Comment: Nice figures and explanations but I don't agree with the term "phase portraits", reserved to cases where the axis represent lagrangian quantities such as $(y,dy/dt)$ with for example energetic considerations.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Good point, I am going to change it to direction field. Thanks.

Comment: I was just writing an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3532274) explaining that this ODE was known under the term "logistic differential equation" and used for population growth modelization with an old history